# Mac shuts down after loading bar loads 50%

Tags: mac, macos, imac, startup

I purchased a new Mac (Apple iMac MK142LL/A - Intel Core i5, 1.6Ghz, 21.5 Inch LED, 8GB, 1TB, Intel HD Graphics 6000, OS X El Capitan). It worked fine the first day.

Since today, when I try to start the iMac, it shuts down automatically after the loading bar loads 50% in the grey screen. After that it will not start until I unplug the power cable and plug again. Same thing again and again.

Comment: If it's a new Mac it'll be covered by Apple's global warranty. I would not hesitate to contact Apple for support. In the meantime you could try starting in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201262) to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: What happens if you go into Disk Repair? You might need a hard drive replacement.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you should absolutely contact Apple about since it is a brand new Mac - it is under warranty and will be replaced, if it's in the first 14 days you can even return it to the Apple store & get a brand new one (or your money back) with absolutely no questions asked.

If you do want to troubleshoot this, try to boot in [verbose mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) by holding command+v during startup - take a picture & post it as a comment here.